# WP7: navigating to custom made page

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-7

I created a new page, I have the skeleton in .xaml, but the content of the page is dynamically generated. How am I able to navigate to this page ? Is there another way than setting the root frame's content to the new page? In the latter case I cannot handle the back key press event on the new page, because the mainpage's backkeypress event is fired instead :(

Comment: Can you update your question (with code samples) to try and explain exactly what you are trying to do. I get that you want to create a page at runtime but I don't get why you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/yourpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
```

Comment: The problem is that yourpage.xaml contains almost nothing. The page's content is generated in the following way: 

YourPage page = new YourPage();
Canvas c = new Canvas();
...
page.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(c);

So when navigating with Navigate(), the empty page shows up, instead of the contents of page :(

Comment: @Vic - Can you do the page init in the new page? You can pass querystring parameters to the page with the information needed to setup the new page.

Comment: @Vic What do you want create the new page in code? this takes a lot of resources.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I write a framework, the user writes the program, so the user fills the pages with controls, the .xaml is hidden from the user, but I can navigate only by Navigate() which accepts a Uri, or by directly setting the content of the PhoneApplicationFrame ((App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Content = page;...). Do you know a better way to do this?